# Slideshow only show one file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

hi everyone i try to make slideshow with php code and jquery and the code like here

```
 <?php
                  $terkini=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM berita WHERE headline='Y' ORDER BY id_berita DESC LIMIT 5");
                  $no=1;
                  while($t=mysql_fetch_array($terkini)){      

                  $isi_berita = strip_tags($t['isi_berita']); 
                  $isi = substr($isi_berita,0,150); 
                  $isi = substr($isi_berita,0,strrpos($isi," ")); 

                  echo "<div class='camera_wrap camera_azure_skin' id='cameraslide'>
                                        <div class='camera-slide-wrapper span8' data-src='foto_berita/$t[gambar]'>
                                            <div class='camera_caption fadeFromLeft'>
                                                <a href='berita-$t[judul_seo].html'>$t[judul]</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>";

                  $no++;  }
                  ?>
```

but as i see its only show 1 news slide even i call it with 5 news from database thanks.

Comment: where is the html and jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing only one newsslide as I guess you are updating all the data in the same div... so the data is getting overriden. Guess, the code should be something like this...

```
<?php


              echo "<div class='camera_wrap camera_azure_skin' id='cameraslide".$no."'>
                                    <div class='camera-slide-wrapper span8' data-src='foto_berita/$t[gambar]'>
                                        <div class='camera_caption fadeFromLeft'>
                                            <a href='berita-$t[judul_seo].html'>$t[judul]</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>";

              $no++;  }
              ?>
```

i.e. guess you forgot to append the $no variable to the div id....